# Postfix: recipient_bcc_maps for incoming mails only

Tags: postfix

With the parameter `recipient_bcc_maps` in `main.cf` from Postfix it is possible to send incoming mails from a list of email addresses as a BCC copy to other email addresses.

I want to BCC copy only those incoming mails where the sender's domain can not be found in the list of `virtual_mailbox_domains` from `main.cf`. That means I don't want to send emails as a BCC copy where Postfix is the "home" server for those domains.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to limit the [`recipient_bcc_maps`](https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#recipient_bcc_maps) only for inbound mail, which is actually the default behaviour...

> The BCC address (multiple results are not supported) is added when mail enters **from outside of Postfix**.

...but not in a way you suggest here: there is no configuration parameter that would allow you to bind `recipient_bcc_maps` with `virtual_mailbox_domains` like that. What you could do is to configure this for the `smtpd` instance listening on port `25` for inbound mail, alone, in the `master.cf`:

```
smtp      inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
  -o recipient_bcc_maps=hash:/etc/postfix/recipient_bcc
```

This way it won't affect your configuration for `smtps` (`465`) or `submission` (`587`) instances of the `smtpd` that are configured for accepting outbound mail from authenticated users.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. However, I don't think it will help me in our constellation. We use Kopano Groupware which uses postfix as MTA. In this respect there is no direct authentication of users to postfix, but to Kopano to send mails.

Comment: What mechanism Kopano uses to communicate with Postfix? Could Kopano authenticate against Postfix or at least use, e.g., `localhost:465`, which would enable separate Postfix configuration for inbound mail?